# Почему мне приходится явно указывать тип при добавлении в список?

Tags: c#, .net, перегрузка-операторов, unsafe

Имеется простой на вид код:

```
/// <summary>
///     Description for video, audio tracks and subtitles.
///     It contains id, name (description string).
/// </summary>
public interface ITrack
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Track Id.
    /// </summary>
    int Id { get; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Track name.
    /// </summary>
    string Name { get; }
}

internal class TrackDescription : ITrack
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

internal unsafe struct Track
{
    internal int Id;
    internal IntPtr Name;
    internal Track* Next;

    public static unsafe implicit operator TrackDescription(Track track)
    {
        byte[] bytes = null;

        int size = 0;
        sbyte* bytePtr = (sbyte*)track.Name;

        while (*bytePtr != 0)
        {
            size++;
            bytePtr++;
        }

        Marshal.Copy(track.Name,bytes, 0, size);

        return new TrackDescription
        {
            Id = track.Id,
            Name = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes)
        };
    }

    public static unsafe implicit operator LinkedList<ITrack>(Track track)
    {
        Track* current = &track;
        LinkedList<ITrack> list = new LinkedList<ITrack>();

        while (current != null)
        {
            list.AddLast((TrackDescription)(*current));
            current = current->Next;
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Почему при добавлении в список элемента, мне приходится явным образом указывать каст к типу `TrackDescription` который должен реализовать интерфейс?

Т.е. я не могу просто разыменовать указатель, и предположить вызов оператора преобразования `list.AddLast((*current));`, ведь оператор помечен как `implicit`, а толку от него нет?

Comment: А если list будет типа LinkedList<TrackDescription>, неявное преобразование подхватится?

Comment: Подхватывается, однако, возвращаемый тип нет.

Comment: Ок, пишите явно значит. Компилятор недостаточно умен. Можно попробовать открыть ишью на гитхабе (если такого еще нет)